# Verify correct use of Chi-Squared method

Tags: statistics

I have a data set which I obtained from experiment. I which to compare this with expected values obtained from $y=2^x$. Could this be done with the Chi-squared distrobtion:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{x} & \text{Obtained y} & \text{Expected y} & \text{Diffrence} & \text{Chi-Term} \\ 
\hline
\\1 & 1.01 & 1 & 0.99  & 0.49005 
\\2 & 3.99 & 4 & 0.01  & 0.000025 
\\3 & 8.86 & 9 & -0.86 & 0.09245 
\\4 & 16.02 & 16 & -0.02 & 0.000025 
\end{array}$$

The Chi-squared value = 0.58255. There are 4 values and 1 varible so $df = 3$. The critical value for p=0.05 is 7.82 and therefore statistically the data fits the theotical funciton $y=2^x$ well.

Is this correct procedure? If not how would I do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, what you have done is correct. However,  any cell, where the expected value is less than a certain tolerance (say, $t$)  is usually ignored. The accepted value for $t$ is currently $5$ but some statisticians take $t$ as high as $10$.  See Wikipedia for more details, in particular, the section on assumptions.

In your problem, if you remove the first and the second cell then you get a very small z-score and hence $y = 2^x$ fits extremely well with your data.